# Magento 2 : Blank/White Category Pages after migration to 2.1 Enterprise

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am facing this problem from quite long time as some of the categories are coming with blank white pages while some pages are working fine.

In some cases I have **updated and saved** from admin and it started working , but it was not with other categories.

**Error in support_log.txt**

> [2017-04-18 05:43:24] report.INFO: Cache file with merged layout:
>   LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_49278eaafaf9de4c42d5b55412f9e812e and handles
>   default, catalog_category_view, catalog_category_view_type_layered,
>   catalog_category_view_type_layered_without_children,
>   catalog_category_view_id_75, restriction_privatesales_mode: Please
>   correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
>
> [2017-04-18 05:43:24] report.INFO: Cache file with merged layout:
>   LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_45dcc9f48fb8f2751b136e5b4ab591b22 and handles
>   wide_left: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

Please suggest , how to fix?

Comment: These logs are not helpful. Check with debug.log and exception.log and update your question.

Comment: I have solved the issue. Some custom options of layouts(which existed in M1) for categories were there which I deleted and its solved the issue.